# Using COUNTIFS function displays incorrect information in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a column in excel with dates named "Next Action Date Due", and I am trying to count and display the number of dates that fall within 1 week from today (TODAY())

I tried both of the following column formulas

```
=COUNTIFS(Table22[Next Action Date Due],"<=TODAY()+7",Table22[Next Action Date Due],">=TODAY()")
```

and

```
=COUNTIFS(Table22[Next Action Date Due],"<=TODAY()+7"&">TODAY()")
```

both of them seem to display the wrong number and also if I change one of the dates in the column to fall within range it still isn't counted. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(Table22[Next Action Date Due],"<=" & TODAY()+7,Table22[Next Action Date Due],">=" & TODAY())`

Comment: Nice, I would advice using `Table22[Next Action Date Due],"<" & TODAY()+8` for the first condition instead of `Table22[Next Action Date Due],"<=" & TODAY()+7` in case the date column is actually date & time formated as date.